# Parse String to Integer (come hell or high water)

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

I need to maintain a legacy VB.NET web application. Data typing is, I would say, inconsistent. Especially, there are data that is stored sometimes as integers and sometimes as strings, and I have to parse strings to integers reliably. If parsing goes wrong it should always return 0.

The problem is, I can't use any of the .NET/VB.NET parsing functions for this, but I have to rely on a self-made function.

Could I use a one-liner standard framework call to do every String-to-Integer parsing task?

Let's say there is a string that can be null, empty, contain an integer representation like "10" or contain something else.

I have tried these with an **empty input string ""**:

```
CType(string, Integer) -> Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
Convert.ToInt32(string) -> Input string was not in a correct format.
Integer.Parse(string) -> Input string was not in a correct format.
CInt(string) -> Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
Val(string) -> Success!
```

But even Val can fail. The surefire way is to call a self-made function:

```
   Public Function ToInteger(ByVal s As String) As Integer

        s = Trim(s)
        Dim i As Integer

        Try
            i = Val(s)
        Catch ex As Exception
            i = 0
        End Try

        Return i

    End Function
```

I think this sucks. This is bad because:

- I'm trying to parse strings to integers! This is not rocket science, even if semantics are involved
- Self-made standards do not stick very well. Somewhere in the code you will always find broken standard framework solutions

As a result there are unnecessary bugs in the software. And I accuse the standard framework for this. Unless, of course a better solution is found :)

---

Thanks for all the answers. Int32.TryParse is perfect here.

But if you have to cast the input to a string first, the cast can fail. Like when reading from a database object with a possible DBNull value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) and ignore the return value - just use the value in the `out` parameter.

Comment: Actually @Jon Int32.TryParse trims white space for you automatically.  `"       32     "`  will result in `32`.

Comment: @David: Thanks, removed that last sentence. It's even documented to trim it :)

Answer (score 7):

You didn't clarify why you couldn't use ".NET/VB.Net parsing functions" so I'll propose this:-

```
Public Function ToInteger(ByVal s As String) As Integer
    Dim i as Integer
    Integer.TryParse(s, i)
    Return i
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Int32.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

Is a two-liner good enough? The following is C# code, but I'm sure you could port it to VB.NET without too much issue:

```
int i;
if(!Int32.TryParse(MyString, out i)) i=0;
```

Actually, because `TryParse` will set i to zero if parsing fails, you don't need the if statement:

```
int i;
Int32.TryParse(MyString, out i);
```

Comment: The reason you don't need to initialize it isn't because the default is 0, but because it's an out parameter - its previous value is irrelevant.

Comment: True - I got hung up on the question's stipulating it should return 0 if parsing goes wrong, thinking the behavior was undefined if it fails (out = it has to set /something/ but not necessarily zero). Of course, checking the documentation for TryParse indeed reveals that i would be set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing lots of string parsing and are unsure what might be in the string you could try using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Two or three well-chosen regular expressions should dump out whatever you are looking for.

A tool like [regexbuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) is invaluable in a situation like this. It would allow you to design a regular expressions for your strings in a GUI environment where you could test them on your various alternatives.

For example, the following will match a number anywhere in a string and match multiple numbers separated by spaces.

```
(\d*)
```

Regular expressions are sometimes thought to be a bit scary, but they don't need to be.