# Converting string to integer VB.NET

Tags: vb.net-2010

I'm having trouble finding the right format for converting my txtID and txtCatID into integers since it's in numbers in the database access.

#### Code

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim sqlinsert As String

    sqlinsert = _
        "INSERT INTO Products (ProductID, Product, UnitPrice, CategoryName, CategoryID)" & _
        " VALUES (@ProductID, @Product, @UnitPrice, @CategoryName, @CategoryID)"
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlinsert, con1)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ProductID", (txtID.Text)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Product", txtProd.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@UnitPrice", txtPrice.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@CategoryName",txtCategory.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@CategoryID", (txtCatID.Text)))

    con1.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con1.Close()

    ClearTextBox(Me)
    RefreshDGV()
    Me.Close()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse String to Integer (come hell or high water)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519675/parse-string-to-integer-come-hell-or-high-water)

Answer (score 3):

You can convert String to int by doing like this:

1. For C#: `int val = Int32.Parse("12");`
2. For VB.NET: `Dim val as Integer = CInt("12")`

Here you can find all [Type Conversion Functions (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx).

Here you have [How to: Convert a String to a Number (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert string from a TextBox to an integer using:

```
Dim myInt as Integer = CInt(Textbox1.Text)
```

Otherwise, if you are asking how to ensure that an integer is appended into an SQL file or [Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access) file using VB.NET, then that's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it:

```
Dim productID As Integer

If (Integer.TryParse(txtID.Text, productID)) Then

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ProductID", productID))
Else
    Throw New ArgumentException("Entered ProductID is not a valid integer.")
End If


cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Product", txtProd.Text))

Dim price As Double
If (Double.TryParse(txtPrice.Text, price)) Then

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@UnitPrice", txtPrice.Text))
Else
    Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid.")
End If

cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@CategoryName", txtCategory.Text))

Dim id As Integer
If (Integer.TryParse(txtCatID.Text, id)) Then
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@CategoryID", id))
Else
    Throw New ArgumentException("Entered Category ID is Invalid.")
End If
```